# How can I access another APK file put within my Android project?

Tags: android

I have an apk file. I create other android project. I place the apk file within that project. Is it possible to access the Activities in the apk from within the new project (similar to importing classes in a jar)?

Comment: Simply No . You can not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot link one APK into another. You can either include the sources and resources from it (perhaps as an Android library project) to access its contents directly, or you can require that the user install it as well and you can invoke its intents.